# Axios POST request reloads page even after e.preventDefault() : React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, forms

So I'm building a dummy social media application for my resume with NodeJS, MongoDB and React. As such, I have a NewPost form in which user can attach videos or images as files and enter their post captions. I have used Multer on Backend and I have tested my route on Postman and BackEnd is working fine. The only problem is that my form won't send the data at all. I have tried `e.preventDefault()` but as soon as I make POST axios request the page reloads and I get Request Aborted error in console and since the data is not sent to BackEnd, no posts are created.

One more odd thing I noticed is that when the content is image, posts are created - maybe because by the time it reloads, the images are uploaded already. In any case, my BackEnd is fine - the only problem is with the form.

Here is my NewPost Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './NewPost.css';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const NewPost = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    formData.append('user', params.userId);
    console.log(formData.get('user'));
    console.log(formData.get('content'));
    console.log(formData.get('caption'));
    const content = formData.get('content').name;
    const imgExt = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'avif', 'apng', 'pjp', 'webp', 'svg', 'bmp'];
    const ext = content.split('.')[1];

    let url;
    if (imgExt.includes(ext)) url = `/api/v1/posts/create/contentImage`;
    else url = `/api/v1/posts/create/contentVideo`;

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(url, formData);
      if (res.data.status === 'success') {
        console.log('Post created successfully!!');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container new-post-box">
      <div className="login-form new-post-form">
        <button
          className="btn-mobile-nav new-post-box-close-btn"
        >
          <ion-icon name="close" class="overlay-close"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <h2 className="heading-secondary heading-login ma-bt-lg">Whats on your mind</h2>
        <form className="form form--login" id="login-form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div className="form__group">
            <label className="form__label" htmlFor="caption">
              Caption
            </label>
            <input
              className="form__input"
              id="caption"
              type="text"
              name="caption"
              placeholder="This is an example"
              required="required"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="file-input-box">
            <label className="form__label" htmlFor="caption">
              Upload Content
            </label>
            <input
              className="form__upload"
              type="file"
              name="content"
              accept="video/*, image/*"
              id="content"
            />
            <label htmlFor="content" className="form__label fileInput">
              Choose file
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form__group">
            <button className="btn btn--green postSubmitBtn">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewPost;
```

NewPost.css

```
.form__upload {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.form__upload:focus + label {
  outline: 3px solid #673ab7;
  outline-offset: 3px;
}

.form__upload + label {
  color: #673ab7;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #673ab7;
  padding: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form__upload + label:hover {
  background-color: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.new-post-box {
  margin: 4rem auto;
}

.form__label {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.form__label.fileInput {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.postSubmitBtn {
  margin: 1rem 11rem;
}

.login-form.new-post-form {
  max-width: 51rem;
  padding: 4.4rem 7rem;
  position: relative;
}

.file-input-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  gap: 2.4rem;
}

.newpost-caption-closebtn-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.btn-mobile-nav.new-post-box-close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 14px;
}
```

Run it on your local machine and please tell me what Im doing wrong. I have almost completed my project and this is for my resume. Without thi working, my entire 2 months hard work will go to waste! Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you remove the axios call, does the page still get refreshed?

Comment: @Anthony C no it doesnt. Axios call is what causes the page to reload, as title of Q says

Comment: Do you use axios interceptors somewhere else? Or does your backend return a redirect response? I ran your code in my env. I got error as expected since the api doesn't exist in my local but I don't get the reload behavior

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem, after researching i found that it caused by live server extension if you are using or any extension, it cause to refresh the page whenever new file is upload in working directory, so you can prevent it by changing location of the upload folder to out of working directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).